# How to write hive queries to csv file using Beeline ranger

Tags: csv, hive, echo, putty, beeline

I am new to hive and I am trying to run a hive query using Putty and I want the output in CSV format without over writing files in the directory. I used following query

```
echo `beeline-ranger --outputformat=tsv2 -e 'select distinct xyz from database.table;' > /C:/Users/name/Documents/TBA /sample_${TODAY}.tsv`
```

I am trying to run this in putty hive environment but I am getting below error

```
ParseException line 1:59 character '<EOF>' not supported here
```

What is wrong with the code, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    This can help you with a solution

    beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://[databaseaddress]' --outputformat=csv2 -e 'select * from table' > theFileWhereToStoreTheData.csv

OR

    beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://[databaseaddress]' --outputformat=csv2 -f yourSQlFile.sql > theFileWhereToStoreTheData.csv
```